# Making an optional Argument in discord py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to make a code where if no one is mentioned then it should consider the person using it as a target.

Here is what I tried so far.
`@bot.command()

async def bal(ctx,*,member: discord.Member= None):

if member == None:

```
member = ctx.message.author



purse = db.get(member)

await ctx.send(purse)
```

`
But it's not working

Comment: What error did you get? There is nothing wrong with your code from the information provided. What does `db.get(member)` return? Is your indentation correct?

Answer (score 0):

first of all it should be
ctx.author
not
ctx.message.author
and u should put the * at the end I think
it should like sth like this

```
@bot.command()
async def bal(ctx,member: discord.Member= None,*):
    if member == None:
         member = ctx.author
    purse = db.get(member)
    await ctx.send(purse)
```

Comment: Not working sir. `async def bal(ctx, member: discord.M ember= None,*):

SyntaxError: named arguments must follo w bare *`
new error.

Comment: `ctx.author` and` ctx.message.author` is the same thing. They both return the message author.

Answer (score 0):

Using `*` means that you are forcing the user to input keyword only arguments, but in your case it's not needed and i think is probably giving you an error since it's a `bare *`.

So following on what bishoy did

```
@bot.command()
async def bal(ctx,member: discord.Member= None):
    if member == None:
         member = ctx.author
    purse = db.get(member)
    await ctx.send(purse)
```

This will remove the error, no need for the `*`